# sklearn LabelEncoder to combine multiple values into a single label

Tags: python, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I am looking to run classification on a column that has few possible values, but i want to consolidate them into fewer labels.

for example, a job may have multiple end states: `success`, `fail`, `error`, `killed`. but i am looking to classify the jobs into either a group of end states (which would include `error` and `killed`) and another group (which will only include `success` and `fail`).

I cannot find a way to do that in sklearn's LabelEncoder, and other than manually changing the target column myself (by assigning `1` to `success` or `fail` and `0` to everything else) i cannot find a way.

***EDIT***
example. this is what i need to happen:

```
>>> label_binarize(['success','fail','error','killed', 'success'], classes=(['success', 'fail']))
array([[1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

unfortunately, `label_binarize` (or LabelBinarizer, for that matter) does it for each column separately. THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT:

```
>>> label_binarize(['success','fail','error','killed', 'success'], classes=['success', 'fail'])
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check out `label_binarize`.  You could set the `success` as the only class, thereby defaulting the rest to 0.  Same result as changing the data prior to encoding, but might fit better into your pipeline.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
label_binarize(['success','fail','error','killed', 'success'], classes=['success'])
```

Output

```
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

Comment: that is a good option, and i have not defined the problem well enough...
i need `classes` to be a list of labels, and still get a 1d array for the target. edited the question with an example.

Comment: So just take the max of each array